# How to write a redis scan command to match either of two patterns

Tags: redis

I want to use HSCAN match clause to match a key which is of type 1 or type 2. A regex would be like `^match1|^match2`. Is it possible to do this in glob style pattern.

Comment: As of version 6.0 you can use the "TYPE" option to ask SCAN to only return objects that match a given type, allowing you to iterate through the database looking for keys of a specific type. The TYPE option is only available on the whole-database SCAN, not HSCAN or ZSCAN etc. Do you mean you want to match the name of the key?

Comment: Yes keys starting with either match1 or match2. Assume i have a * also there

Answer (score 1):

Redis does not offer a straight forward way to match multiple patterns.
Redis matchs using glob-style pattern which is very limited.

Supported glob-style patterns:

- h?llo matches hello, hallo and hxllo
- h*llo matches hllo and heeeello
- h[ae]llo matches hello and hallo, but not hillo
- h[^e]llo matches hallo, hbllo, ... but not hello
- h[a-b]llo matches hallo and hbllo

Use \ to escape special characters if you want to match them verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use glob-style for that, but you can Lua your way around this. That means you can use 
[`EVAL`](https://redis.io/commands) and a script (can be similar to https://github.com/itamarhaber/redis-lua-scripts/blob/master/scanregex.lua) for performing the `HSCAN match1*` first, and then filtering with Lua on `match2.*`.